# Rational Team Concert: Team Area users to have access to a different project

Tags: user-management, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

We've got several projects in RTC for both source code and planning/bug tracking. Sometimes, the projects depend on each other and we would like to link the work items between the projects. However, to do this, the user needs to have rights to create work items in both projects.

The work around is to dump all the required users to the other project as well, but I'm wondering if there is a way to give all the users from a team area within one project access to the work items in a separate project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default Access Control (Members of the project hierarchy), you can see why it is required to dump the required users in the other (or both) projects. You've said "only people specifically in this project may read items in this project". I'm not quite sure how VonC's answer would work if the users still don't have at least read access to the project area. I'm assuming these project areas are served from the same server/repository.

One way to handle this without having to make them members of the other project is to adjust the Access Control to Members+Access List and add the necessary people to the access list. This will only give them read access (which may be sufficient -- not clear from your description) and avoids polluting the project hierarchy with them (assuming they need not be part of it).

Another (much looser option) is to open up Access Control so Everyone (who can log in to your repository) has access, then restrict what the Everyone/default role can do. This may be where VonC was heading with his response. If the extra visibility isn't a problem for your situation, this may be the easiest answer and would not require extra access control manipulation.

Comment: Thanks Millard - even though it is not exactly what I was looking for (the access list still requires dumping individual users), it is probably the best what can be done with current RTC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a role, to which you associate specific right, for work-item only.

The association is done in the `Team configuration / permission` section of the Project Area:

[image: Permissions]

That way, a resource who has all the rights in one project would only have work-item rights in the other project.